# where should I use new → I see everywhere?

Tags: links

I currently use
[image] to refer to an external link on my personal website.

However recently I have started noticing extended use of → for links. Is this a replacement for [image] ? or is it used to convey some other meaning?

Comment: Can you post an example URL using the new icon you mention?

Comment: http://geoffreygrosenbach.com/

Answer (score 6):

People use all sorts of things for links. Use whatever makes sense for your actual design. The icon you're currently using is fairly common and well-known. For whatever it's worth, I don't think I've ever encountered that → character in this use. Asking if it's a replacement kind of assumes there's a standard in the first place; there isn't.

Such indicators have largely gone out of fashion in my own experience. I probably only see them anymore on sites that by nature are very heavily internally linked and so external links really are a bit of an oddity, eg. Wikipedia. Anywhere else, it's just an assumed possibility that you might get sent off-site.

Comment: Yes, there is not standard for marking external links. The diagonal arrows you showed seem to be copied off of wikipedia. Some other sites I've seen use a different colour (e.g. green internal, blue external.) On slashdot.org they simply name the site in (brackets) after the link. I had never seen the use of → before though it does have some advantages. → is a text character so one can type it easily where as your diagonal arrows are a small image that needs downloading.

Comment: Plus one for "Asking if it's a replacement kind of assumes there's a standard in the first place; there isn't."

Answer (score 2):

Semantically I think → is an incorrect choice for external links because to me that reads like 'continue on in this direction'.  I also don't know how that is read by a screen reader (being that it is a text character and all)

That being said, as Su' has mentioned, there is no standard nor any real need to adopt one.